# In the brief passage that I present, is "were awoken" or were awakened" grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage, verbs

Vicky Smith of Snowflake, Arizona, said she was asleep in bed when she and her dogs were awoken by a loud noise.

Answer (score 2):

More often than not...***"awakened"*** is used in a sense where one was being shown the truth behind some idea or thought. I.E. - "The world was awakened to the evils of terrorism on 9-11."

Where as ***"awoken"*** would be more regarding a literal waking up from sleep.
 So, according to the contextual meaning of your mentioned sentence ***were awoken*** is the most appropriate answer.

Comment: Though I think just 'woken up' would be the most proper usage.